# JSP parse error

Tags: java, jsp

This the first time I've tried using JSP and I'm getting a parse error at the link in the last line.  I already have a ";".

```
<%@page contentType="application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8" %><%
String
baseURL = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() +
request.getServerPort()+ ":" + request.getContextPath();
Integer id=0;
String link="";
%>

<feed xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom ../XMLschemas/atom/atom.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <title type="text">1</title>
    <id><%=baseURL%></id>
    <updated>2012-04-23T15:49:17Z</updated>
    <link rel="self"
        href="https://example.com" />
    <entry>
        <id><%link = baseURL + "/" + Integer.toString(++id); %><%=link%></id>
```

in Weblogic:

```
feed.jsp:69:16: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
                <id><%link = "good_subjectdoc_relativeurl.xml"%></id>
```

The rest of the feed:

```
    <title type="text">good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.xml
        </title>
        <updated>2012-04-23T15:49:17Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name>TEST</name>
        </author>
        <contributor>
            <name>TEST</name>
        </contributor>
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/xml" title="Subject Document"
            href="<%=link%>" />
            <category term="TEST" />
                <content>
                                    Content             
                              </content>
    </entry>
```

Comment: Is that your entire JSP?  Do you close `<entry>`?

Comment: @BrandonV, Yes I closed entry.  I pasted the rest of the feed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> feed.jsp:69:16: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

As the error says, you need to insert `;` to complete statement on the following line:

```
<id><%link = "good_subjectdoc_relativeurl.xml"%></id>
```

Thus, so:

```
<id><%link = "good_subjectdoc_relativeurl.xml";%></id>
```

Comment: I have a ";" This is what I have:> "<%link = baseURL + "/" + Integer.toString(++id); %><%=link%>" which gets translated to: "<%link = "good_subjectdoc_relativeurl.xml"%>" without the ";" for some reason.

Comment: Are you running the code you think you're running? Rebuild/redeploy/restart.

Comment: Yes I just redeployed. In the log I also wee an arrow starting at the equals sign and ending at the 'x" after the dot: ^------------------------------^